# Return true if the string in the first element of the array contains all of the letters of the string in the second element

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I tried to do this by resetting loop going trough firstword every time its letter matches with secondword letter.

```
function mutation(arr) { 
  var compare = [];
  var firstword = arr[0].toLowerCase();
  var secondword = arr[1].toLowerCase();
  var j = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < firstword.length; i++) {

      if (firstword[i] === secondword[j]) {
      compare.push(secondword[i]);
      i = -1;
      j++;

      
      
      
    }
  }
  let result = compare.join("")
  if (result.length === secondword.length) {
    return true;
    
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

console.log(mutation(["Noel", "Ole"]));
```

It works in some cases but in others, like above example, it doesn't. What seems to be the problem?

Comment: `compare.push(secondword[i]);` should be `compare.push(secondword[j]);`

Answer (score 1):

You need to `compare.push(secondword[j])` instead of `compare.push(secondword[i])`

```js
function mutation(arr) {
  var compare = [];
  var firstword = arr[0].toLowerCase();
  var secondword = arr[1].toLowerCase();
  var j = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < firstword.length; i++) {
    if (firstword[i] === secondword[j]) {
      compare.push(secondword[j]); // Correction here
      i = -1;
      j++;
    }
  }
  let result = compare.join("");
  if (result.length === secondword.length) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

console.log(mutation(["Noel", "Ole"]));
```

Also, you can consider using [Array.prototype.every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every).

```js
const mutation = ([first, sec]) => {
  const lowerCaseFirst = first.toLowerCase();
  const lowerCaseSec = sec.toLowerCase();
  return Array.from(lowerCaseSec).every((ch) => lowerCaseFirst.includes(ch));
};

console.log(mutation(["Noel", "Ole"]));
```

If the strings are small then [String.prototype.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) works fine but if they are large then you should consider using a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set).

```js
const mutation = ([first, sec]) => {
  const firstSet = new Set(first.toLowerCase());
  const lowerCaseSec = sec.toLowerCase();
  return Array.from(lowerCaseSec).every((ch) => firstSet.has(ch));
};

console.log(mutation(["Noel", "Ole"]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple ES6 Function, we check with .every() if every characters of secondword is includes inside firstword. It return true if it does.

```js
function mutation(arr) {
          const firstword = arr[0].toLowerCase();
          const secondword = arr[1].toLowerCase();
          return secondword.split('').every(char => firstword.includes(char));
}

console.log(mutation(["Noel", "Ole"]));
```

Answer (score 0):

The use of `Set` in SSM's answer works if you don't need to account for duplicate characters in the second string. If you do, here's an implementation that uses a `Map` of character counts. The map key is the character from string 1 and the value is the number of occurrences. For instance, if you want `["Noel", "Ole"]` to return `true`, but `["Noel", "Olle"]` to return `false` (string 1 does not contain 2 "l" characters). String 2 is then iterated through and character counts decremented if they exist. As soon as a character is not present or the count falls below 1 in the map, the function returns `false`.

```
function mutation(arr: string[]): boolean {
    return s1ContainsAllCharsInS2(arr[0].toLowerCase(), arr[1].toLowerCase());
}

function s1ContainsAllCharsInS2(s1: string, s2: string): boolean {
    if (s2.length > s1.length) {
        return false;
    }
    let charCountMap: Map<string, number> = new Map<string, number>();
    Array.from(s1).forEach(c => {
        let currentCharCount: number = charCountMap.get(c);
        charCountMap.set(c, 1 + (currentCharCount ? currentCharCount : 0));
    });
    return !Array.from(s2).some(c => {
        let currentCharCount: number = charCountMap.get(c);
        if (!currentCharCount || currentCharCount < 1){
            return true;
        }
        charCountMap.set(c, currentCharCount - 1);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A different approach.

Mapping the characters and comparing against that map.

```js
function mutation(arr) {
  const chars = {};

  for (let char of arr[0].toLowerCase()) {
    chars[char] = true;
  }

  for (let char of arr[1].toLowerCase()) {
    if (!chars[char]) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  return true;
}

console.log(mutation(["Noel", "Ole"]));
console.log(mutation(["Noel", "Oleeeeeeeeeeeee"]));
```

If the count also matters *(your code doesn't take it into account)* you can count the number of occurrences of each character and comparing these counts.

```js
function mutation(arr) {
  const chars = {};

  for (let char of arr[0].toLowerCase()) {
    chars[char] = (chars[char] || 0) + 1;
  }

  for (let char of arr[1].toLowerCase()) {
    // check if chars[char] contains a (not empty == positive) count
    // then decrement it for future checks
    if (!chars[char]--) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  return true;
}

console.log(mutation(["Noel", "Ole"]));
console.log(mutation(["Noel", "Oleeeeeeeeeeeee"]));
```